# Counting unique values in a column with a shell script

Tags: bash, awk, unique

I have a tab delimited file with 5 columns and need to retrieve a count of just the number of unique lines from column 2. I would normally do this with Perl/Python but I am forced to use the shell for this one.

I have successfully in the past used *nix uniq function piped to wc but it looks like I am going to have to use awk in here.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. (I have asked a similar question previously about column checks using awk but this is a little different and I wanted to separate it so if someone in the future has this question this will be here)

Many many thanks!
Lilly

Answer (score 22, accepted):

No need to use awk.

```
$ cut -f2 file.txt | sort | uniq | wc -l
```

should do it.

This uses the fact that tab is `cut`'s default field separator, so we'll get just the content from column two this way. Then a pass through `sort` works as a pre-stage to `uniq`, which removes the duplicates. Finally we count the lines, which is the sought number.

Comment: This is great. After messing around I discovered that I can find any dupes by this
cat file.txt | awk '{print $2}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n

Answer (score 5):

I go for

```
$ cut -f2 file.txt | sort -u | wc -l
```

At least in some versions, `uniq` relies on the input data being sorted (it looks only at adjacent lines).

For example in the [Solaris docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1461/uniq-1.html#scrolltoc):

> The uniq utility will read an input
>   file comparing adjacent lines, and
>   write one copy of each input line on
>   the output. The second and succeeding
>   copies of repeated adjacent input
>   lines will not be written.
>
> Repeated lines in the input will not
>   be detected if they are not adjacent.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{if($0~/Not Running/)a++;else if($0~/Running/)b++}END{print a,b}' temp
```